# GCC warning flag for Semantic Issue

Tags: xcode, gcc

I'd like to silence Semantic Issue warning but I don't know the warning flag for this type.
Do you know the flag name?

ie: **#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsequence-point"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#pragma GCC diagnostic` can only be used with options shown by `-fdiagnostics-show-option`

Compile with `-fdiagnostics-show-option` to see whether there is some `[-Wfoo]` at the end of the warning message.